# How to convert list into schema in r?

Tags: r, list, schema, apache-arrow

The code is as below:

```
schema = schema(`Key`=int64(),
                 Sex = string(),
                `Age` = int64(),
                `Date of Birth` = date32(),
                `Institution` = string(),
                `Admission Date` = date32(),
                `Discharge Date` = date32(),
                `Elderly Home` = string(),
                `Paycode` = string())

class(schema)
```

R returns:

```
Error in `check_schema()`:
! `schema` must be an object of class 'Schema' not 'list'.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> class(schema)
[1] "list"
```

Is it possible to convert the list into `schema`?
[image]

[image]

The version that I run :
The version should be Arrow package version: 11.0.0.2.

```
> arrow::arrow_info()
Arrow package version: 11.0.0.2

Arrow options():
                       
arrow.use_threads FALSE
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Defining `schema = schema(...)` returns an object of class `"Schema"`, `"ArrowObject"`, `"R6"`.

Comment: But I got the result list...The screen cap is updated.

Comment: which version of the arrow package are you using? Do you have other packages loaded?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the error you are describing, but we can turn a `list` object into a  `schema` by using `rlang::inject()`:

```r
library(arrow)

schema_ls <- list(
     `Key`=int64(),
     Sex = string(),
     `Age` = int64(),
     `Date of Birth` = date32(),
     `Institution` = string(),
     `Admission Date` = date32(),
     `Discharge Date` = date32(),
     `Elderly Home` = string(),
     `Paycode` = string())


rlang::inject(schema(!!!schema_ls))
#> Schema
#> Key: int64
#> Sex: string
#> Age: int64
#> Date of Birth: date32[day]
#> Institution: string
#> Admission Date: date32[day]
#> Discharge Date: date32[day]
#> Elderly Home: string
#> Paycode: string
```

Regarding the error shown in the OP, below is what I'm seeing:

```r
library(arrow)

schema = schema(`Key`=int64(),
                Sex = string(),
                `Age` = int64(),
                `Date of Birth` = date32(),
                `Institution` = string(),
                `Admission Date` = date32(),
                `Discharge Date` = date32(),
                `Elderly Home` = string(),
                `Paycode` = string())
class(schema)
#> [1] "Schema"      "ArrowObject" "R6"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Still cannot work, the result is updated

Comment: To better understand what error you are seeing and where it is coming from, we would need an reproducible example, probably with some data, and the function calls your are making.

Comment: I just run the code that I provided...

Comment: @doraemon: If I run your code everything is working as expected (see updated answer). You could try: i) restarting your R session, 2) loading only the 'arrow' package and run the code again. If you still get arrows, let us know which version of arrow you are using.

Comment: As others have said, the package version would help.  You can run `arrow::arrow_info()` to get information about the arrow package version.

Comment: `check_schema` was [introduced in arrow-11.0.0.2](https://github.com/cran/arrow/blame/b0f53c5217835ed8365fd0c8070ae784065a9d2b/R/dataset-format.R#L300) (no changelog listing yet), so it seems likely to be either 11.0.0.2 or 11.0.0.3 (current) (or dev?).

Comment: @r2evans: I'm using version 11.0.0.3.

Comment: @doraemon what version are you running? It's been requested a few times ...

Comment: `check_schema()` is an internal function used for checking that everything lines up when someone is using `open_dataset()` and provides both a schema and column names.  It isn't exported from the package, and isn't intended to be used in other contexts.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I had something to work last night... The version that I run is updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `arrow::schema` not work is that:

```
> library(plotly)

Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:arrow’:

    schema

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout
```

Therefore, the `arrow::schema` function cannot be correctly executed.